# The charge keeps jumping

Tags: laptop, charging

My laptop's charge has been jumping all the way to 0% when not plugged in,causing it to shut off a lot.

Not sure if it's a virus or my laptop's battery went bad,(it wasn't doing this before).Anyone have an idea on what's happening?

Comment: What laptop? Original battery? Original charger? How old is the battery? What's the history of the problem? (Was it working fine and then one day suddenly starting shutting off? Did it gradually get worse?)

Comment: Well,It's a HP laptop,I don't really remember where the battery and charger came from,and the battery,if I remember correctly,came with the laptop.If it did,it's about a year and a few months old. ( And yes,It was working fine a few months ago,and it recently started shutting off,and it's been getting worse,and It's happening more often..)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds precisely like a modern (Li-ion) battery going bad, based on a few dozen I've dealt with.

In some cases the timescale can be aggravated by sub-optimal power management software combined with "battery-abusive" behavior (leaving it plugged in all the time, say, where better power management software will not abuse the battery) and in other cases mere "battery-abusive" behavior suffices (running it all the way flat and leaving it discharged, say) or treating a Li-ion like a satellite NiCad (the very specific partial discharge case that is oft-misinterpreted as a reason to run the battery flat every time.)

In many operating systems your power management software will have information about its read on battery health. Behavior like "at 50%, suddenly at zero" is a battery going bad, in my experience. If that was a new laptop you might want to check with the maker about sub-optimal battery lifetime (you should get more than 2 years in normal use) as it's not unknown for defective batches of batteries to go out, and recall/replacement to happen, but sometimes only to customers who call and complain about the problem (the annoying "silent recall.")

If the laptop was "new to you, but not new" (not clear to me which it is given what you say about the battery and charger) it might simply be normal battery lifetime.